# Airflow DAGs failed to be triggered

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I just started working with Airflow recently and after writing a simple DAG to transfer data from sftp server to s3, I ran into this error when I triggered the DAG: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_dagrun'**. Does anyone have experience with this? Thank you so much

```
with dag:
 # test ssh connection
t1 = SFTPOperator( task_id='download_file_from_sftp',
ssh_conn_id='sendeffect_evania',
local_filepath="/tmp/test.csv",
remote_filepath='sftp://evania@11335-04.root.nessus.at/files/download/evania_daily_bounce.csv',
operation='get' )
```

Comment: Can you share your code to understand the problem ? All i could think of is while defining task you might have forgotten to add dag=dag at the end of the task.

Comment: Hic I have defined it but it still didn't work :(( Thank you though. This is my operator: with dag:
    # test ssh connection
    t1 = SFTPOperator(
        task_id='task_id',
        ssh_conn_id='my_conn',
        local_filepath="/tmp/test.csv",
        remote_filepath=f'{sftp_file_path}',
        operation='get'
    )

Comment: Hi! If my answer worked for you then please mark it as accepted as the answer would be more visible and would be easier for others to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have shared i think you have not used proper syntax to write the DAG.
Try to use the below:

```
import datetime as datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
with DAG('my_dag', start_date=datetime(2016, 1, 1)) as dag:
    (
         t1 = SFTPOperator( task_id='download_file_from_sftp',
         ssh_conn_id='sendeffect_evania',
         local_filepath="/tmp/test.csv",
         remote_filepath='sftp://evania@11335-04.root.nessus.at/files/download/evania_daily_bounce.csv',
         operation='get' )
    )
```